# Вывести данные из вложенной? структуры в UITableView

Tags: массивы, swift, struct

Никак не получается вывести в UILable/UITableView следующий кусок вложенной структуры.
Мне нужно передать из одного контроллера в другой (UITableView).
Единственный вариант, когда, что-то выводится в ячейке, если я передам так:

```
 controller.countryInfo.append([String(country.currencies?.description ?? "")])
```

при это в ячейке выводится вот такое: ) Я понимаю, что это из-за .description, но это хоть что-то, что я смог вывести.

```
[App.Currency(code: "AFN", name: "Afghan afghani", symbol: "؋")]
```

А должно быть:

```
AFN, Afghan afghani, ؋
```

Подскажите, как правильно сделать? )

```
struct Element: Codable {
 
    let currencies: [Currency]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currencies = "currencies"
    }
}

struct Currency: Codable {
    let code: String
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "code"
        case name = "name"
        case symbol = "symbol"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто, добавь в структуру метод или что-то другое, что будет возвращать нужную тебе информацию, например если нужна информация о одном элементе `Currency`:

```
struct Currency: Codable {
    let code: String
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "code"
        case name = "name"
        case symbol = "symbol"
    }
    
    // Можно такое: переменная только с get методом
    var decoratedDescription: String {
        return code + ", " + name + ", " + symbol
    }
    
    // Или так: что бы менять разделитель
    func decoratedDescription(_ separator: String = ", ") -> String {
        return code + separator + name + separator + symbol
    }
}
```

Ну и использовать соответственно:

```
currencies[indexOfElement].decoratedDescription
// output: "AFN, Afghan afghani, ؋"

// или

currencies[indexOfElement].decoratedDescription()
// output: "AFN, Afghan afghani, ؋"
```

Если нужно делать для всего массива, то так же есть много решений, например в структуру `Element` добавить методы для вывода:

```
struct Element: Codable {
    let currencies: [Currency]?
    
    var decoratedDescription: String {
        var arrayOfStrings: [String] = []
        currencies?.forEach { curr in
            arrayOfStrings.append(curr.decoratedDescription)
        }
        return arrayOfStrings.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
    
    func decoratedDescription(_ separator: String = ", ") -> String {
        var arrayOfStrings: [String] = []
        currencies?.forEach { curr in
            arrayOfStrings.append(curr.decoratedDescription(separator))
        }
        return arrayOfStrings.joined(separator: separator)
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currencies = "currencies"
    }
}
```

Тогда используем так:

```
country.decoratedDescription
// output: "AFN, Afghan afghani, ؋, AFN2, Afghan afghani2, ؋"

// или

country.decoratedDescription()
// output: "AFN, Afghan afghani, ؋, AFN2, Afghan afghani2, ؋"
```

Так же все зависит еще от ситуации, как и что и куда ты хочешь передать. Попробуй описать более детальней что и куда передается? В каком формате? Что должно быть? Больше кода. Что ты ожидаешь в результате?

Comment: Попробовал оба варианта, ошибка —  Value of type '[Currency]' has no member 'decoratedDescription'


Не видит .decoratedDescription

Comment: @Dmitry Да мой провтык, мой пример подходит ели ты берешь decoratedDescription с одного элемента, например:

```
country.currencies[0].decoratedDescription
```

Сейчас обновлю ответ для списка

Comment: Я уже разобрался, я добавил еще один пустой массив и через for в него добавил, и потом уже этот новый массив передал на следующий viewcontroller. Все работает.
Но вы напишите как еще можно сделать. Мой вариант, скорее всего не самый оптимальный.

Comment: @Dmitry Добавь код своего решения и тогда на этом примере могу помочь с оптимизацией